# What do these spring session keys stand for in Redis?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, redis, spring-session

I'm integrating Spring Session, Spring Security with SpringBoot by following this [tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot.html).

The solution works well for me. It saves sessions to Redis as expected.

I'm curious what do these keys/values(such as expirations, index, sessions:expires) stand for. Anyone knows about it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`RedisOperationsSessionRepository` Storage Details](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/#api-redisoperationssessionrepository-storage) part of Spring Session's reference manual covers the storage related implementation details in depth. You can find the same information in [javadoc of `RedisOperationsSessionRepository` class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/redis/RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java#L78-L240).

In short, expirations/expires is related to internal handling of session expiry, and index stores indexes which can be used to retrieve sessions using [`FindByIndexNameSessionRepository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/#api-findbyindexnamesessionrepository).